# Obfuscator's "Prevent Microsoft IL Disassembler from opening my assembly" option

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation, reverse-engineering

I've been trying to apply code protection using the SmartAssembly obfuscator to a WPF Prism application, but it the application refuses to work properly when being obfuscated.

The only option that works for it is: ***Prevent Microsoft IL Disassembler from opening my assembly***.

The Red-Gates help describes it as: *SmartAssembly can add an attribute to your assembly that prevents Microsoft's Common Intermediate Language (IL) Disassembler (ildasm.exe) from opening your assembly*.

I wonder how serious is this protection, is it worth to be applied if the code isn't really obfuscated.
Or, in other words, what is it this **Microsoft's Common Intermediate Language (IL) Disassembler (ildasm.exe)**? Is it the main part of every known .NET reverse engineering tool or is it just one of the many such tools?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ildasm.exe is the IL disassembler that comes with the .Net Framework. It's the one tool that everyone has if they have .Net. It's not a component, so other disassemblers are not based on it or anything.

The attribute in question is the [`SuppressIldasmAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223407.aspx). I do not know if other disassemblers such as Reflector or ILSpy respect this attribute, but I doubt it. A cursory Google search suggests that is not the case, and that the `SuppressIldasmAttribute` only affects ildasm.exe itself.

As such, it doesn't really protect your assembly and isn't much use as an obfuscation tool. But if you are obfuscating anyway, I don't see any reason why you wouldn't apply this attribute, as it at least blocks the easiest (most commonly available) method of disassembly and I don't think it does any harm.

Comment: The attribute is `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.SuppressIldasmAttribute`, and it doesn't stop Reflector.

Comment: Edit `ildasm.exe`, search for `SuppressIldasmAttribute`, replace one letter to something else, save. Done, it will not complain anymore.

Comment: Best answer, easy peasy with x32dbg